# What is the word for "understanding someone's level of understanding"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

My associate was explaining a concept to do with distributed datasets on the whiteboard to some people at work. He was making a judgement about how much they understood.

I think they understood it more than he gave them credit for, and he continued to explain after they had got his big idea.

I'm trying to find a word to describe "his understanding of their understanding".

Here is what I have come up with so far:

- cognitive empathy
- meta epistemology
- pedagogical epistemology
- skill in teaching

My question is: **What is the word for "understanding someone's level of understanding"?**

Comment: An associated concept is 'pitching the material at their level'. In education, 'assessment' and 'level 3 (etc)' are keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assessing comprehension** of material during presentations by asking questions such as,

> "Does this make sense to everyone?"

and

> "Does anyone need more information?"